# Why is the styling of these nearly identical pages different?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating my first custom WordPress theme and can't figure out why two nearly identical category template files are being displaying differently.

The black-colored band at the bottom of [this page](http://bugsandbubs.com/category/adventures/) should extend across the entire width of the page, like it does on [this page](http://bugsandbubs.com/category/projects/), but for some reason it's not.

The code for the correctly-styled template file is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<body class="projects">

<div id="page-container">

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="post-container">

                <div class="post-title">
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h3>
                </div>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(''); ?>       
                </div>

                <div class="post-footer">
                    <p>BY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div><p>CATEGORY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></p><img id="comments" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments.png" height=20px></a></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="#"><p>44</p><img id="likes" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/likes.png" height=20px></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div id="more-posts">
                <a href="<?php next_posts_link(''); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/more.png" width=200></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

The code for the incorrectly-styled template is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<body class="adventures">

<div id="page-container">

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="post-container">

                <div class="post-title">
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(''); ?>       
                </div>

                <div class="post-footer">
                    <p>BY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div><p>CATEGORY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></p><img id="comments" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments.png" height=20px></a></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="#"><p>44</p><img id="likes" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/likes.png" height=20px></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div id="more-posts">
                <a href="<?php next_posts_link(''); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/more.png" width=200></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>         

    </div>

</div>
```

Both category template files are structured the same (as far as I can tell) and use the same style sheet, so I am at a loss as to why they are being displayed differently by the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/217863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in place of my original answer, since you changed the question.  Turns out you are missing a closing `</div>`.  The problem doesn't manifest itself on the first page because you only have one post, but I bet if you added another, you'd see the same thing.  The snippet below focuses just on your while loop, and should fix your problem if you add the closing `</div>` where I've indicated via a comment.

```
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>  <!-- *** you open this but never close it *** -->
                <div class="post-container">
                    <div class="post-title">
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <?php the_content(''); ?>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-footer">
                        <p>BY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div><p>CATEGORY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></p><img id="comments" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments.png" height=20px></a></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="#"><p>44</p><img id="likes" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/likes.png" height=20px></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div> <!-- *** need to add a closing div here - I've added it for you *** -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it's missing any `</div>` closing tag, I think it's just an honest mistake of pasting the `<footer>` in the wrong place.

Comment: true, i changed my answer to "might be", because it might be.  Chances are you are right though and it's just in the wrong place.

Comment: True that, I think I looked close enough and just found that it's just a case of the `<footer>` element being pasted one closing `</div>` too soon.

Comment: I added an extra closing </div> which fixed the styling problem, but when I used the W3 code validator it said I had an extra closing </div> and referenced the line of code where I had just added the closing </div>. Thoughts?

Comment: Jumped the gun with my answer before looking at your comment, where did you add the extra closing </div>?  In the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your footer in the http://bugsandbubs.com/category/adventures/ is inside your `#page-container` so it's only growing 945px like it's parent.

If you move your `<footer>` element outside the `<div id="page-container">` you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The pages are ALMOST identical... but on the page with the incorrect styling you have some mistakes...

All you got wrong is the images URLs;

Because the images have a different actual size that the one you are setting up on the css... when the url is broken/wrong this messes up the page styling...

I would suggest to fix the links and also add on your style.css file on line 151:

```
#social img {
    width: 145px;
    height: 30px;  /* ADD THIS */
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a validator to check for issues, use the w3schools validator tool found here http://validator.w3.org/

enter your URL and it will show you what errors it finds.

You can select a box under where you enter your URL to show source code.  This will allow you to quickly view your troubled area.

I hope this helps, Good Luck!