# Similarly structured WordPress template files producing different CSS styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two nearly identical WordPress category template files that are being displayed differently in the browser.

The black-colored band at the bottom of [this page](http://bugsandbubs.com/category/adventures/) should extend across the entire width of the page, like it does on [this page](http://bugsandbubs.com/category/projects/), but for some reason it does not.

Both category template files are structured the same (as far as I can tell) and use the same style sheet, so I am at a loss as to why they are being displayed differently by the browser. Adding an extra closing  to the incorrectly styled page seems to solve the problem, but I can't figure out why an extra closing  is necessary in the one template file, but not in the other.

The code for the correctly-styled template file is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<body class="projects">

<div id="page-container">

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="post-container">

                <div class="post-title">
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h3>
                </div>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(''); ?>       
                </div>

                <div class="post-footer">
                    <p>BY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div><p>CATEGORY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></p><img id="comments" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments.png" height=20px></a></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="#"><p>44</p><img id="likes" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/likes.png" height=20px></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div id="more-posts">
                <a href="<?php next_posts_link(''); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/more.png" width=200></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

The code for the incorrectly-styled template is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<body class="adventures">

<div id="page-container">

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="post-container">

                <div class="post-title">
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(''); ?>       
                </div>

                <div class="post-footer">
                    <p>BY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div><p>CATEGORY:</p><div class="post-footer-item"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></p><img id="comments" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments.png" height=20px></a></div><div class="post-footer-action"><a href="#"><p>44</p><img id="likes" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/likes.png" height=20px></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div id="more-posts">
                <a href="<?php next_posts_link(''); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/more.png" width=200></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>         

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why have you asked this question twice?! Duplicate is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848474/why-is-the-styling-of-these-nearly-identical-pages-different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first notice that you have an opening tag inside `while(have_posts())` (`<div <?php post_class(); ?>>`), but that the closing tag is included regardless of whether there is a post or not.

Also, have a look at your source (or better yet, get Firebug). In the example that is incorrect, your `<footer>` element is inside `<div id="page-container">`, where as in the other one it is below it. Is there more to your source then the section you posted, as I cannot see a call to `get_footer();` on either example?